# Django multiple of the same dependent dropdownboxs in one form

Tags: django, drop-down-menu

I have a problem with the following;
I have a dependent dropdown menu in a Django model form. Now I want to use it several times in the same form but I can't get it to work if I load more than one then I can only enter/use one. And I have a 2nd problem if this works how do I get the different values in a list/array so that I can store them in the db?
The ultimate goal is to select how many beams are desired and on that basis to be able to enter the desired hours, ion species, energy and flux per beam.

My code is as follows:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from smart_selects.db_fields import ChainedForeignKey


class IonSpecies(models.Model):
#   ionspecie = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)


    def __str__(self):
#       return self.ionspecie
        return self.Name

class Energys(models.Model):
    Ion_Species = models.ForeignKey(IonSpecies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
#       return self.energy
        return self.Name

        
# Create your models here.
class CreateBeamRequestModel(models.Model):

    #status choices
    SELECT      = 'Select'
    REQUEST     = 'Request'
    TENTATIVE   = 'Tentavive'
    ACCEPTED    = 'Accepted'
    CONFIRMED   = 'Confirmed'
    CANCELLED   = 'Cancelled'
    COMPLETED   = 'Completed'
    QUEUED      = 'Queued'

    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (SELECT, ('Select an option')),
        (REQUEST, ('Request')),
        (TENTATIVE, ('Tentative')),
        (ACCEPTED,  ('Accepted')),
        (CONFIRMED, ('Confirmed')),
        (CANCELLED, ('Cancelled')),
        (COMPLETED, ('Completed')),
        (QUEUED, ('Queued')),
    ]

    #different beam choices (1 to 4)
    DIFBEAMS_CHOICES = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,5)]

    #shift choices (1 to 16 is max a week)
    SHIFTS_CHOICES = [tuple([x,x]) for x in range(1,17)]

    #fields of the model
    Project_Code = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20, blank = True)
    Pac_Rate = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank = True)
    Partrec_Contact_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True)
    Partrec_Contact_Email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    Previous_Experiment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank = True)
    Status = models.CharField(max_length=25, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='SELECT')
    Project_Title = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank = True)
    Spokesperson_Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True)
    Spokesperson_Adress = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True)
    Spokesperson_Phonenumber = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank = True)
    Spokesperson_Email = models.EmailField(blank = True)
    Collaborator_Name = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Collaborator_Nationality = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Collaborator_Home_Institute = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Different_Beams = models.IntegerField(choices=DIFBEAMS_CHOICES, default='1')
#   Shifts = models.IntegerField(choices=SHIFTS_CHOICES, default='1')
    Hours = models.IntegerField(default='1')
    Ion_Species = models.ForeignKey(IonSpecies, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Energy = ChainedForeignKey(Energys, chained_field="Ion_Species", chained_model_field="Ion_Species", show_all=False, auto_choose=True)
    Flux = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank = True, null = True)
    Start_Date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    End_Date = models.DateTimeField(blank = True, null=True)
    Requiered_Equipment = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Special_Requirements = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Special_Safety_Procedures = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Lab_Support_Requirements = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Funded = models.TextField(blank = True)
    Summary = models.TextField(blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Project_Code

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return f"/beamrequest/{self.Project_Code}"

    def get_edit_url(self):
        return f"{{self.get_absolute_url}}/update/"

    def get_delete_url(self):
#       return f"/beamrequest/{self.Project_Code}/delete/"
        return f"{{self.get_absolute_url}}/delete/"
```

forms.py

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block extrahead %}
    
{% endblock %}

{% block title %}{{ title }}{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

    <form method="post" novalidate>
        {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="Error_Messages">
            {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
                {{ error }}
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <b>Internal contact information</b>
        <hr class="divider"></hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Project_Code|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Partrec_Contact_Name|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Pac_Rate|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Partrec_Contact_Email|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Previous_Experiment|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
             
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Status|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
             
         </div>
        </div>
        <br><br>
        <b>External contact information</b>
        <hr class="divider"></hr>

        <div class="row justify-content-center">
         <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Project_Title|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Spokesperson_Name|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Spokesperson_Adress|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Spokesperson_Phonenumber|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Spokesperson_Email|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-4">
            {{ form.Collaborator_Name|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            {{ form.Collaborator_Nationality|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
         <div class="col-4">
            {{ form.Collaborator_Home_Institute|as_crispy_field }}
         </div>
        </div>
         <br><br>
         <b>Beam information</b>
         <hr class="divider"></hr>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.Start_Date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
             {{ form.End_Date|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-6">
            {{ form.Different_Beams|as_crispy_field }}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div id="hidden1">
                <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.Hours|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Ion_Species|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Energy|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Flux|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hidden2">
                <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.Hours|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Ion_Species|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Energy|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Flux|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hidden3">
                <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.Hours|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Ion_Species|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Energy|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Flux|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="hidden4">
                <div class="col-6">
                {{ form.Hours|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Ion_Species|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Energy|as_crispy_field }}
                {{ form.Flux|as_crispy_field }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          {{ form.Requiered_Equipment|as_crispy_field }}
          {{ form.Special_Requirements|as_crispy_field }}
          {{ form.Special_Safety_Procedures|as_crispy_field }}
          {{ form.Lab_Support_Requirements|as_crispy_field }}
          {{ form.Funded|as_crispy_field }}
          {{ form.Summary|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save New Request</button>
        </div>
    </form>
<br>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#hidden2').css({
       'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#hidden3').css({
       'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#hidden4').css({
       'display': 'none'
    });
    $('#id_Different_Beams').on('change', function() {
       if (this.value === '2') {
           $('#hidden1').show();
           $('#hidden2').show();
           $('#hidden3').hide();
           $('#hidden4').hide();
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == '3') {
           $('#hidden1').show();
           $('#hidden2').show();
           $('#hidden3').show();
           $('#hidden4').hide();
       }
       else if ($(this).val() == '4') {
           $('#hidden1').show();
           $('#hidden2').show();
           $('#hidden3').show();
           $('#hidden4').show();
       }
       else {
           $('#hidden1').show();
           $('#hidden2').hide();
           $('#hidden3').hide();
           $('#hidden4').hide();
       }
    });
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.http import Http404, HttpResponse

from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404, redirect


from .models import CreateBeamRequestModel, IonSpecies, Energys
from .forms import CreateBeamRequestForm

# Create your views here.

#home page
def beam_request_home_page(request):
    page_title = 'Beam Request'
    template_name = 'request/home.html'
    context = {"title": page_title}
   
    return render(request, template_name, context)

#@login_required
#Create view
@staff_member_required
def beam_request_create_page(request):
    page_title = 'Create new Request'
    template_name = 'request/create.html'

    form = CreateBeamRequestForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        form.save()
        form = CreateBeamRequestForm()
    context = {"title": page_title, "form": form}
           
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your question. You want multiple instances of the `Different_Beams` field? (Side note: You have some very non-standard naming conventions going there ...)

Comment: Hello, the thing i would like to have is to select 1,2,3 or 4 different_Beams. and then for each beam select the ion species and energy. So if i have 2 beams selected i would like to select for example the ion species Helium with the energy 30 and the ion species Nitrogen with an energy 50. And i am new to programming and just use naming that i can understand easly. I will have a look into standard naming conventions.